# Photos are suddenly duplicated between iPhoto and Aperture; any methods to de-dupe?

Tags: photos.app, photos, aperture

I have a library for iPhoto and a separate library for Aperture.

A random sampling of hundreds of events (ex: "Jun 22, 2014") which consists of thousands of photos are suddenly appearing in Aperture. I thought they may be coming from both my iPhoto and Aperture libraries at the same time, but they're actually duplicates from iPhoto in the Aperture library.

The event folders aren't complete; they may only have a fraction of the photos that iPhoto has in the same event.

None of the iCloud options in my preferences are enabled, as I thought they may be coming in from some iCloud sync action, but that's (probably) not the case.

Are there any remedies anyone can suggest to de-dupe this? It's pretty frustrating since my libraries are very large (90gb for iPhoto, 130gb for Aperture).

Comment: Yosemite? I'm wondering if this is some none-too-subtle preparation for the demise of iPhoto & Aperture... readying for the new combined photo app.

Comment: Macericks actually.